# SBT support for custom ivy module status?

Tags: sbt, ivy

In my SBT build I have a dependency on an ivy artifact that makes use of a custom module status. This causes the following error in SBT:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: my-org#myapp-core_2.11;1.0: java.text.ParseException: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://artifacts.myorg.com/libs-snapshots-local/myapp-core_2.11/1.0/myapp-ivy.xml': bad status: 'snapshot';
```

I can work around this by telling SBT to use an external ivy settings, like so:

```
externalIvySettings(baseDirectory(_ / "ivySettings.xml"))
```

And then create an ivySettings.xml containing the following:

```
<statuses default="release"> 
  <status name="release" integration="false"/> 
  <status name="snapshot" integration="false"/> 
</statuses>
```

But surely there must be a better way? The problem with this work around is that now all my settings (such as resolvers) have to be in the ivy file too, because (IFAIK) it's all or nothing when you use externalIvySettings.

Is there a way to specify a set of custom statuses within my build.sbt? Or alternatively is there a way to tell sbt to combine external ivy settings with the ones it generates from the build.sbt.

Since specifying custom module statuses is a valid thing to do in ivy, this should really be supported in sbt too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because for some repositories, they use non-standard status which fails the consistency check. We addressed this by constructing the customized resolver which doesn't do consistency check. You can also construct resolver with the custom status using the same approach. The following is the working snippet.

```
  resolvers += {
  val resolver = new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver
  resolver.setName("Custom Ivy Snapshots")
  resolver.setRoot("http://Custom/snapshots/")
  val settings = new org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings()
  settings.setVariable("ivy.local.default.ivy.pattern", Pattern)
  settings.setVariable("ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern", Pattern)
  resolver.setSettings(settings)
  resolver.setM2compatible(true)
  resolver.setCheckconsistency(false)
  new RawRepository(resolver)
}
```